# Ni multisim 11 resonant circuit problem

Tags: circuit-design, multisim, resonance

I'm trying to simulate parallel resonant ciruit. I'm also useing Bode analyzer but the result is different from what it should be.
My circuit:

[image]

And the result is:

[image]

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L is 16.4 mH and C is 6.2 nF. This means the resonant frequency is 15.8 kHz. Your bode plot shows 100 Hz to 15.8 kHz and this looks just right to me. I'd expect the output to be low at 100 Hz (zero at DC) and rise until it reaches about 15.8 KHz then tail off as the frequency rises above 15.8 kHz.

Unfortunately your bode plot only goes to 15.8 kHz so it isn't showing the full picture. Try plotting it up to 1 MHz and also use dBs as the vertical scale for gain. Make sure that the sweeping increments are small enough to capture the detail in the full picture.

You could also try increasing R to maybe 1k or 10k and seeing how the peak shape improves. This demonstartes the effect of Q-factor on a resonant circuit. All important for the learning process.

Comment: How to make sweeping increments smaller? I thought I could set precision by number of steps.

Comment: My main point is make the sweep go up to 1 MHz to see the full picture.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I can see proper image. I simply don't know why there are only 5 points on graph per decade while there are 200 steps per decade in options.

Comment: I can't help on that one, sorry. If I have answered your question please consider formally accepting it.